# Combining these two functions into one

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

Hey guys I have a password validator that I amd having issues working on, its quite lengthy and I think can be shortened down and simplified if possible.

Could someone assist me in simplifying it. Im talking about the **checkValidPassword()** function.

```
function check(input) {
    if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
        input.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
    } else {
        // input is valid -- reset the error message
        input.setCustomValidity('');
        // check the length of the password
        checkValidPassword(input);
    }
}


function checkValidPassword(input) {
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm password');
    if (password.value.length < 8) {
        password.setCustomValidity('Password must contain at least 8 characters!');
    } else {
        var re = /[0-9]/;
        if (!re.test(password.value)) {
            password.setCustomValidity('password must contain at least one number (0-9)!');
        } else {
            password.setCustomValidity("");
        }
    }
}
```

And im trying to implement a way for the user to must include atleast a number also. I was thinking about

```
str.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/)
```

Would I include that in the if statment with **$$** to symbolize *and also check characters* ?

```
if(password.value.length < 8 && str.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a code review question, but ok... I'd rewrite your function to something like:

```
function checkPassword() {

    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm password');

    if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
        password.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
        return false;
    }

    if(password.value.length < 8 ) {
        password.setCustomValidity('Password must contain at least 8 characters!');
        return false;
    }

    if(!/[0-9]/.test(password.value)) {
        password.setCustomValidity('password must contain at least one number (0-9)!');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Basically, check each condition individually and return immediately if it fails, thus avoiding extra indentation ("early exits"). This is a bit verbose, but far more readable than a monster regular expression, especially if you don't know for sure what it does.

Comment: Thanks @georg , Currently im using **<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<input id="password_confirm" name="password" type="password" oninput="check(this)"  />** Would I keep that oninput(checkthis) function? or change it to **checkPassword()**?

Comment: Just `checkPassword` will be fine.

Comment: thank you for your assistance but it doesn't seem to be working here is a jsf: http://jsfiddle.net/xb4u0453/ i am calling it correctly.

Comment: @xtrman: you need to use the "no wrap" option and double-check if all IDs match.

Comment: I am very confused on where I should be adding the no wap option and where to check if id's match.

Comment: that works perfect, but whats the point of a error box if Its gonna show as a tooltip message with customvalidator?

Comment: @xtrman: it's just an example. I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xb4u0453/3/ I pretty much set validation messages via the tooltips that popup under the input boxes where the required is shown. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out, I combined them both by just putting the else into one another.

```
function ValidatePassword(pass, confirm_pass) {
    if (pass.value != confirm_pass.value || pass.value == "" || confirm_pass.value == "") {
        confirm_pass.setCustomValidity("the Passwords do not match");
        pass.setCustomValidity("the Passwords do not match");
    } else {
      if(pass.value.match(/(?=^.{8,30}$)([a-zA-Z]+[0-9])$/)) {

            pass.setCustomValidity("");
            confirm_pass.setCustomValidity("");


        } else {
             pass.setCustomValidity("the password doesnt have numbers");
            confirm_pass.setCustomValidity("the password doesnt have numbers");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I made the form look like:

```
<form>

        password
        <input id="pass" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password" />
        <br> confirm
        <input id="confirm_pass" type="password" required="" placeholder="confirm" onfocus="ValidatePassword(document.getElementById('pass'), this);" oninput="ValidatePassword(document.getElementById('pass'), this);" />
        <br> username :
        <input id="username" required="" type="text">
        <br>
        <button class="btnform" name="register" type="submit">Complete Registration</button>
</form>
```